# Central Limit Theorem doubt about definition

Tags: probability, statistics

im new to Statistics so please just dont blast me if my question seems stupid for you :(

I studied the Central Limit theorem via the Khan Academy video, and know i know that

> The central limit theorem states that the sampling distribution of the
>   mean of any independent, random variable will be normal or nearly
>   normal, if the sample size is large enough.

However, i listen to many people saying that

> the sum of many independent random variables will tend towards a
>   normal distribution

The fact is that im new able to reconcile this 2 definitions. Can you help me ?

Comment: Almost! In the second definition, it's the average that converges to a normal distribution. If you make that correction and think about it, these two definitions are actually saying the same thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a random variable $X$ with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$; it does not have to be normally distributed

Now suppose you take a sample size $n$ from this, so each value $X_1,X_2,\ldots,
X_n$ is independently and identically distributed.  You could consider the mean $\bar{X}_n = \frac1n \sum_1^n X_n$ which will have mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, or the distribution of the distribution of the sum of these $S_n=\sum_1^n X_n$ which will have mean $n\mu$ and variance $n \sigma^2$

Informally the Central Limit Theorem says each of $\bar{X}_n$ and $S_n$ will be approximately normally distributed with their respective means and variances.  More formally, as $n$ increases:

- $\sqrt{{n}}\left(\bar{X}_n-\mu\right)$ converges in distribution to that of a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$
- $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to that of a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$

These two statements are equivalent, and represent your two statements